# OpenShift - how to change one gear size in an app with two gears

Tags: openshift

i just scaled my app from small gear to medium, but when i ran `rhc app-create --from ...` it separated my Ruby cartridge & Mongo cartridge into two medium gears.

Is there a way to unify them or change the gear size of Ruby to small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalable apps on OpenShift Online current gen (v2) will always run the database on a separate gear, aside from the application that is scaled over a number of gears. See [Scalable Versus Non-scalable Applications](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/scaling.html#scalable-vs-non-scalable) in the *Developers* portal.

If you want to have the database on the same gear, the app needs to be made non-scalable.

If you want to scale only the application itself over small gears, you can outsource the database or host the database in another OpenShift app (possibly a larger gear size) and access the data as outlined in [this blog post](https://blog.openshift.com/sharing-database-across-applications/).